# Update global variable from inside switch

Tags: c

Perhaps this is a question with an obvious answer, but I'm new to C and have spent hours trying to get this to work by myself and searching on this site.

I'm building a simple program that starts with a variable that holds a number (1234 in this case), and one of the options in the program allows the user to change that variable (value).

So, the user is asked to enter the new number for **`value`** to hold. Then asked for the same numbers again. If the numbers entered are the same, **`value`** should be updated to hold these new numbers (stored in both **`newValue`** and **`newValueCheck`**).

I'm trying to figure out how to update **`value`** by assigning it the numbers stored in the new variables but no matter what I try, when the menu loops around and I ask the program for the numbers in **`value`**, it's always stuck as 1234.

Again, sorry if this is obvious, but it's driving me insane.

```
int x = 1;
int value = 1234;
int enteredValue = 0;
int newValue = 0;
int newValueCheck = 0;

while (x != 0) {
    printf("1. Example");
    printf("2. Change value");
    scanf("%d", &atm);

    switch (x) {

    Case 1:
        //Code here
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Option 2 selected");

        printf("Please enter your new value:");
        scanf("%d", &newValue);

        printf("Please re-enter your new value:");
        scanf("%d", &newValueCheck);

        if (newValue == newValueCheck) {
            printf("You have successfully changed your value.");
            //Code to update 'value' goes here?
        }
        else {
            printf("The values provided do not match. Please try again.");
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Yes, code to update `value` goes where your comment is. Could you provide the whole main method?

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a "scope" issue. Since you declare the variable in the loop, it only "lives" for the duration of that iteration. Declare it before the loop and you should be set

Comment: Apologies! I copied the code in incorrectly. The variable are outside the loop in the code I'm working on, so it's not an issue of scope.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything wrong with the updated code, aside from the lack of any code assigning to value (I presume your real code is doing that). Perhaps if you post what that code looks like instead of a //comment the problem might become clearer

Comment: Oh god. Almost an entire day lost to my life and I think I finally have it. 

int value = 1234;
int *ptr_value = &value; (NEW)
...
blah blah blah
...
*ptr_value = newValue; (NEW)

Is that the best way to go about it? It seems to be working, at the very least.

Comment: That would work fine, but value = newValue; should work fine too.